# Trigger Click Event on aspx Button on an External User Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, webforms

In the following subscribe.aspx file ...

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="subscribe.aspx.vb" Inherits="Company.Website.clsSubscribe_Page" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ucSubscribe" Src="controls/ucSubscribe.ascx" %>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
    <uc1:ucHtmlHead ID="HtmlHead" Title="Subscribe to our Newsletters" Description="Subscribe OurNewsletter"
        Keywords="newsletter, subscription" runat="server" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdV088RFFFEaKMW0y_cxHAr8Ok-l3Ks3xO9"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="formMain" runat="server">
        <div class="internal">
            <div class="content">
                <a name="contentContainer" class="hide"></a>
                <div class="newslettersign-up">
                    <div id="centreColumn" role="main">
                        <uc1:ucSubscribe ID="ucSubscribe" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    function VerifyCaptcha() {

        grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute('6LdV088RFFFEaKMW0y_cxHAr8Ok-l3Ks3xO9').then(function (token) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "subscribe.aspx/VerifyCaptcha",
                    data: "{'response':'" + token + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.d != "null") {
                            var obj = JSON.parse(response.d);
                            var success = obj.success;
                            var score = obj.score;
                            if (success == false || score < 0.5) { 
                                ShowCaptchaFailureMsg();
                            } else {
                                // Check score

                                $("[id$='cmdSubscribe']").trigger('click');  
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            ShowCaptchaFailureMsg();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
    function ShowCaptchaFailureMsg() {
        // Show message on website accordingly
        alert("this is a bot..");
    }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like

```
$("[id$='cmdSubscribe']").trigger('click');
```

To trigger a click on an asp button on ucSubscribe user control

```
<input id="someid" type="button" value="Subscribe" onclick="return VerifyCaptcha();">
<asp:Button ID="cmdSubscribe" Text="Subscribe" runat="server" alternatetext="Subscribe" Style="display: none;"></asp:Button>
```

However, this trigger is not triggering click on the above button.  Not sure why.

Need an alternative way to make trigger this click event on the above button.

Comment: do you see the rendered htlp ? Is the `cmdSubscribe` the same on the page or you need to add the `<%=cmdSubscribe.ClientID%>`

Comment: how about use the `__doPostBack`

Answer (score -1):

Since the problem can result from different issues, the following list will help you troubleshoot your code:

- The code exposed, the javascript function `VerifySub` is not being called, which consequently the `gresub.ready` function is not called as well which will not trigger the click event;
- If your button has an id, you could use `$("#cmdSubscribe").click();` [jquery syntax](https://api.jquery.com/click/) instead;
- What is `gresub`?

Comment: I've updated the above question with a more accurate content.

Comment: I've also tried $("#cmdSubscribe").click(); but didn't work for me.